# How do I add to a rectangular array in a for loop by column and row

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So the problem I am not able to solve is when dealing the shuffled deck to the 2d array, it gives each player 6 cards until it moves to the next row. What I'm trying to do is deal 1 card at a time to first player and then to second player for example:

```
row 1  [dealcard1][dealcard3]  
row 2  [dealcard2][dealcard4]
```

Code:

```
    static String[] shuffledDeck(String[] deck) {
    int counter = 0;
    String[] shuffled = Arrays.copyOf(deck, deck.length);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 1000; j++) {
        if (counter == 52) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
        String s = shuffled[counter];
        shuffled[counter] = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = s;
    }
    return shuffled;
}
```

Deck of cards:

```
static void loadCardArray() {
    String[] suit = {"C", "H", "S", "D"};
    String[] rank = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
    p("This is the deck of cards\n"
            + "Load the deck in order of suits\n"
            + "Show the deck");

    String[] deck = printCardArray(suit, rank);

    p("Shuffle the deck\n"
            + "Show the deck");

    String[] shuffled = shuffledDeck(deck);
    int count = 0;
    // Show the shuffled deck
    for (String d : shuffled) {
        count++;
        p(d);
        if (count == 13) {
            p(" ");
            count = 0;
        }
    }



    String[][] dealCards = new String[4][6];

    String[] hand1 = new String[6];
    String[] hand2 = new String[6];
    String[] hand3 = new String[6];
    String[] hand4 = new String[6];

    int counterr = 0;
    int cardsIndex = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < dealCards.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < dealCards[r].length; c++) {
            // dealing out the shuffled cards
            System.out.print(dealCards[r][c] = shuffled[cardsIndex] + " ");
            counterr++;
            cardsIndex++;
            if (counterr == 6) {
                System.out.println();
                counterr = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The main point of this application is to deal a shuffled deck to 4 players of 6 cards each and currently my output looks like

```
  12H 2S 1D 6H 2H 11D 
  9C 6S 8H 13C 6D 10S 
  11H 5C 11S 3D 1H 1C 
  13D 1S 13S 13H 10H 12S
```

Shuffled deck is

```
12H
2S
1D
6H
2H
11D
9C
6S
8H
13C
6D
10S
11H



5C
11S
3D
1H
1C
13D
1S
13S
13H
10H
12S
```

As you can see player 2 (second row first column) should be [`2S`] instead of [`9C`]. [`1D`] the third card from the shuffled deck should be third players first card.

Comment: `p("");` please edit your question if this is relevant

Comment: @FailingCoder As far as i can tell this is an alias for `System.out.println`

Comment: Please add an example of *input -> expected output* and an actual question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sterconium I have updated the question. I'm just trying to use a rectangular array to hold my hand and output it the way a dealer would in a game of cards

Comment: So the point of your application is just to partition an array (deck of cards) into smaller arrays (hands)?

Comment: `System.out.print(dealCards[r][c] = shuffled[cardsIndex] + " ");` - you shouldn't mix things like this. Note that this will add a space to the elements in `dealCards` which is probably not what you want. Do yourself a favor and split the assignment and the print statement.

Comment: Look at how you're iterating over `dealCards` - `r` (row) in the outer loop and `c` (column) in the inner loop. Thus you're filling a row's columns first before advancing to the next row (player). If you want to go "column first" then switch that, i.e. loop over the columns first and then the rows.